# WD Elements External HDD not showing up its drive even though its recognized?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

I've got a 320GB WD Elements HDD that when plugged in shows up in device manager but it doesn't show its drive in 'MyComputer'. I've tried on several computers and still no luck. Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Comment: I'm tempted to open it up and use my SATA dock to see if I can read it, but I fear I may damage it

Comment: Do not open it. There is a 99% possibility that you will damage your hard drive.

Comment: @TGSInfinity He meant the casing. That will not damage the HDD.

Answer (score 2):

Does it appear in disk management?

If so, delete all the partitions on **THE USB HDD** and reformat

Comment: I'm trying to recover my files before I do any formatting.

Comment: @sil3nt ok, even then, start up disk management and see if the partitions are being recognised at all. If they are, maybe its just a question of mounting them manually

Answer (score 0):

It is originally formatted with exfat, which you need to install on XP and Vista.

Comment: I'm on windows 7, also it was working fine on windows vista computers

Comment: Might be USB power issues, crawl USB device tree in device manager/computer manager - it may show oversubscribed power on some port. Also a common HDD usually needs more electricity than USB port can provide, so you actually need a USB port which has no power limit, pr as a minimum disable power saving on respective USB port (and plug the laptop in the wall)